# Django form integrityerror for concurrent operation on unique fields

Tags: python, django

I noticed a thing that I don't know if it is a real issue or I'm doing some wrong design.

I have a model:

```
class A(Model):
    name = CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
```

and a modelform linked to A, this modelform has a clean_name() method, that checks if that field is unique in the db (ignore the fact that modelforms already do that by default, I'm specifying that for the example here).

In the view if I do

```
o = form.save(commit=False)
# xyz
o.save()
```

and in `#xyz` I have another client that inserts an A object with the same `name` field value, `o.save()` triggers an Integrityerror exception, correctly preventing the duplicate record to be inserted.

What I want to know is how to handle those cases, should I wrap that `o.save()` with a try/except block and then populate the error field on the form specifying to choose another `name` value?

This is somewhat a common case that should happen to everyone and that solution is horrible, so I think I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: Why don't you just do: o = form.save()? That way the next entry won't pass form validation.

Comment: @cchristelis in that case #xyz would be between form.is_valid() and form.save().

Comment: A workaround is to save the object first (using dummy values if some mandatory fields are calculated in `xyz`), and have a bool field named `calculating` that you set to `True` when you are doing `xyz`. When the extra work is done, you can update/delete it depending on the outcome of `xyz`, and set `calculating` to False. Both your suggestion and mine are pretty hackish though, so let's hope somebody else can suggest a better way of doing it.

Comment: Would it be OK to wrap the view with manual transaction plus a select_for_update?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be the case:

Model forms provide uniqueness validation only when a flag is set in `xx_clean()`. If you override `clean` with your own (as you have), you need to call the superclass's `clean()`. See [overwriting the clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method).